# open Get Direction with multiple stops in google map from using objective c ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-urls

I am using google map sdk and now i want to open get direction in google map where **there are multiple stops** like i am at Location **A** and from that i want to go to locations **B,C,D** i am able to open google map with location **A to B** but not able to open it for **A to B,C,D**.
How can i do this i tried this

```
NSString *str1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%@&daddr=%@&waypoints=%@&key=%@",originString,destinationString,strWayPoints,GOOGLE_API_KEY];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str1]];
}
//str1 =
http://maps.google.com/?saddr=18.518205,73.857431&daddr=18.518205,73.857431&waypoints=via:18.518205,73.857431|via:18.552248,73.901596|via:18.629764,73.934685&key=MYKEY
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the answer, but for knowlege purpose : **_Based on the code you have mentioned, you are not using SDK, but a url scheme_**

Comment: yes at this point i didnt use SDK but is there any solution for my problem by using SDK or using URL

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: I want to open get direction but I have single source and multiple destination. Like multiple stops I am not able to open it in Google map

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) that provides universal cross platform syntax to open maps in mobile apps or Google Maps website.

In directions mode, you can specify the origin, destination and multiple waypoints for your route. For more details have a look at the following page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action

Example of URL:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=18.518205,73.857431&destination=18.518205,73.857431&waypoints=18.518205,73.857431%7C18.552248,73.901596%7C18.629764,73.934685`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @xomena , Solution you given to me is not opening the google map on actual device when i do this 
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str] options:nil completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if(success)
            {
                NSLog(@"Google Map open");
            }
        }];`
It always return **NO** . Any solution?

Comment: URL You provided is opening  google map on browser but when i am trying to open it from iphone  my app to google map its not working.Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is code which is now working fine for get direction. I am answering here so that other will get how to use it

```
- (IBAction)onClickNavigate:(id)sender {

NSString *strWayPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", [[destLatArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue], [[destLongArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];
for(int j=0;j<destLatArray.count;j++){
    if(j > 0)
        strWayPoints = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%f,%f", strWayPoints, [[destLatArray objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue], [[destLongArray objectAtIndex:j] doubleValue]];

}
NSString *originString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",[sourceLat doubleValue], [sourceLong doubleValue]];
NSString *destinationString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f", [[destLatArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue], [[destLongArray objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue]];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=%@&destination=%@&waypoints=%@",originString,destinationString,strWayPoints];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"You haven't installed the google map");
}
```

}